# Error: Could not request certificate - Puppet version Issue

Tags: ssl, puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

It was running fine till earlier, now I all of a sudden get this error when I try to do

```
puppet agent --server *MasterName* --waitforcert 60 --test
```

. When I try to `yum upgrade puppet`, I get nothing to do. Any help with this error?

```
Error: Could not request certificate: Find /production/certificate/ca?fail_on_404=true resulted in 404 with the message: {"message":"Not Found: Error: Invalid URL - Puppet expects requests that conform to the /puppet and /puppet-ca APIs.\n\nNote that Puppet 3 agents aren't compatible with this version; if you're running Puppet 3, you must either upgrade your agents to match the server or point them to a server running Puppet 3.\n\nMaster Info:\n  Puppet version: 4.2.2\n  Supported /puppet API versions: v3\n  Supported /puppet-ca API versions: v1","issue_kind":"HANDLER_NOT_FOUND"}
```

Comment: What version of Puppet are you running on the agent and what version on the master?

Comment: If you cannot update your agents to `4.x`, you can try downgrading the master. Please note that the latest versions of `puppetserver` should support Puppet `3.x` agents.

Comment: Peter, I had to control over version. But when I check now master is 4.2.2 and the agent is 3.8.3.